# Logging into a website and retrieving HTML with Python

Tags: python, twill

I need to log into a website to access its html on a login-protected page for a project I'm doing.

I'm using [this person's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2910309) answer with the values I need:

```
from twill.commands import *
go('https://example.com/login')

fv("3", "email", "myemail@example.com")
fv("3", "password", "mypassword")

submit()
```

Assumedly this should log me in so I then run:

```
sock = urllib.urlopen("https://www.example.com/activities")
html_source = sock.read()
sock.close()
print html_source
```

Which I thought would print the html of the (now) accessible page but instead just gives me the html of the login page. I've tried other methods (e.g. with mechanize) but I get the identical result.

What am I missing? Do some sites restrict this type of login or does it not work with https or something? (The site is FitBit, since I couldn't use the url in the question)

Comment: Did you try with "https://example.com/activities" (without the "www") using `urllib`? I have encountered problems when I intermingle non-"www" and "www" URLs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using one library to log in and another to then retrieve the subsequent page. `twill` and `urllib` are not sharing data about your sessions. ([Similar issue to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25965388/1431750).) If you do that, then you need to manage the session cookie / authentication yourself. Specifically, you'll need to copy the cookie + data and add that to the post-login request in the other library.

Otherwise, and more logically, use the same one for both the login and post-login requests.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I just added a `go('https://example.com/activities')`  and `save_html('textfile.txt')` and it works a charm.